# How do I use anaconda stuff in Visual Studio Code WITHOUT launching it from Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I installed anaconda 3, activated it and placed it in my PATH. After that I installed Visual Studio Code, from anaconda navigator, and launched it **from there**. I tried this code

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
    y = np.sin(x)

    plt.plot(x, y)

    plt.show()
```

this code works perfectly fine and does its job. But here's my problem, when I try to open Visual Studio Code without anaconda navigator, this code doesn't work and shows me this message in the TERMINAL:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\ana> conda activate base
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\ana> & C:/Users/user/Anaconda3/python.exe
c:/Users/user/Desktop/ana/cons.py Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/ana/cons.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py",
line 205, in <module>
    _check_versions()   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py",
line 190, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

The thing is code works fine if I don not import `mathplotlib.pyplot`, and thus not using to draw the graph, even if I open VSCode without anaconda environment.
I tried watching dozens of tutorials, but just can't deal with it. I've reinstalled anaconda (and ticked PATH thing), I've reinstalled VSCode, I've restarted my laptop after every try, but no luck. If someone could write detailed solution I'll be so thankful. this whole thing took me whole day, I'm new in python and anaconda, I've only worked with C and C++ before that, so I don't know much about this stuff.

Comment: Which environment do you have selected in VS Code? In the status bar (at the bottom) it should say something like `Python 3.7.4 64-bit ('base': conda)`.

Comment: And did the environment activation work? Your PS prompt suggests that it didn't work.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response! Yes, my environment is set to `Python 3.7.4 64-bit ('base': conda)` . I don't know if it worked, how can I activate so that I'll be sure it works?

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is to open **Anaconda prompt** and then run Visual Studio Code from prompt.

> code

The conda environment is automatically used in VS code. Running from Anaconda Prompt is also much faster than using Anaconda Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\ana> conda activate base
```

wasn't executed properly. Otherwise you would see the environment name in front of the "PS", like

```
(base) PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\ana>
```

This is a known issue with VSCode, because it often takes too long to activate a conda environment compared to e.g. virtualenv environemnts. As a workaround you need to activate your environment manually with the command from above.

Another thing that worries me is that you added Anaconda to your PATH. This is not recommended. Instead let conda initialize itself during the installation. If you skipped that part you need to

```
conda init --all
```

so that you can activate conda environments from all your shells.